# Class Loading Issue in Jboss

Tags: java, jar, jboss, classloader

In my application i'm using gson api and this application is deployed in Jboss 5.0 server. Our Jboss 5.0 server contains many other applications apart from my application. From my application i'm using gson-2.2.4 jar. Rest of the applications have dependency over gson-1.3.jar.

When i start the clone in jboss server, gson-1.3 jar is getting loaded by default and NoSuchMethod error is thrown while accessing gson. If i remove this jar from the classpath folder, then gson-2.2.4.jar is loaded and application is working fine.

My question : Is there any way to override this class loading configuration to load classes from gson-2.2.4.jar instead of any other gson jars in jboss 5.0?

I've gone through the class loading concepts of jvm, but couldnt able arrive to a clear picture for the above scenario, kindly advice.

Comment: What version of JBoss?

Comment: Jboss 5.0, help me on this..

Comment: You should update your description to explain where you are putting the each of the jar files (lib folder, in EAR file, etc).